# How to do timestamp regex given start time and end time?

Tags: python, regex

I was working on extracting the log lines of interest from a huge log file.
Note that I'm not familiar with python at all.

The log line all starts from a timestamp, like

```
09:00:00.648711172 [Info  ] [....]
```

And I want to match it with a specific period of time, say from 09:00 to 09:30, I came up with the following solution:

```
r'^(09:[012][0-9]|30)
```

The problem is this cannot apply to a generic case, say we're given a `start_time` and an `end_time`, how can I do the match?

Comment: What do you mean by generic case? What do you mean by start date and end date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of building your regex pattern for different `start_time` and `end_time`, you can capture and parse the time and compare it with actual time range:

```
import datetime

start_time = datetime.time(9, 00)
end_time = datetime.time(9, 30)

log_line = "09:00:00.648711172 [Info  ] [....]"

log_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(log_line[:log_line.find(".")], "%H:%M:%S").time()
if start_time <= log_time <= end_time:
    print("Woo, we've found a match: {}".format(log_line))
else:
    print("Close, but no cigar with the line: {}".format(log_line))
```

Comment: Exactly what I want! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Only regex won't help you much in this case. Rather you can try to pick up the values of hour, minute and second using a regex, then do some calculation  (something like `hour * 3600 + minute * 60 + second`) to determine if it's in the range or not.

Answer (score 0):

Regex that matches any one entry of date from 09:00:00 to 09:30:00 and doesn't match anything else:

```
log_regex = re.compile(r'09:(([0-2]/d{1}):([0-5]/d{1}|60))|30:00')
```

You want to match all occurrence for this regex:

```
log_regex.findAll(your_string_variable)
```